# scrapying a h3 tag returns null

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm learning Scrapy. As an exercise I want to get the product title in this web page https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_json/ using this code:

```
scrapy shell "https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_json/"
response.xpath("//h3[1]/text()")
```

> []

but the only thing I get is nothing (a zero dim dic).

Comment: Obviously you need to get JSON content from the source, `json.loads()` it and next get your `title` value from a JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'title')]/text()")
```

if you press control+u you can see this information at the footer

> var obj = {
>       "title": "Short Sweatshirt",
>       "price": "$24.99",
>       "description": "Short sweatshirt with long sleeves and ribbing at neckline, cuffs, and hem. 57% cotton, 43% polyester. Machine wash
>   cold.",
>       "img_path": "/static/img/" + "96230-C" + ".jpg" };

Comment: thanks for ur responses. I followed ur recommendations and wrote followed codes: >> scrapy shell "scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_json/"; res=response.xpath("//script[contains(.,'title')]/text()") json.loads(res)